# Sorting a Map<Object, List<Object>> by Object Parameter in Java

Tags: java, sorting, object, stream, maps

Can you please help me sort a map like this

```
Map<Object, List<Object>> halls = new HashMap()<>;
```

where the key Object has one of his parameters to be numberOfSeats
and the whole map should be sorted by the most number of seats in reverse order.
I tried doing it with streamAPI but i can't seem to make it work.

Something like:

```
 halls.entrySet().stream().sorted((h1, h2) -> h1.getSeatsNumber.compareTo(h2.getSeatsNumber));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `HashMap`, create a `TreeMap` which is sorted by key and provide a custom comparator:

```java
Map<MyObject, List<MyObject>> halls = new TreeMap<>(
        Comparator.comparingInt(MyObject::getSeatsNumber).reversed()
);
```

If you have a collection of `MyObject` that needs to be collected into map, this can be done using `Collectors.groupingBy` with a supplier of the `TreeMap`:

```java
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<>(); // input list of MyObject

Map<MyObject, List<MyObject>> halls2 = list
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            x -> x,
            () -> new TreeMap<>(
                Comparator.comparingInt(MyObject::getSeatsNumber).reversed()
            ),
            Collectors.toList()
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use comparing by key for example:

```
halls.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparing(YourObject::numberOfSeats).reversed()))
            .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (s1, s2) -> s1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

And if you want to sort map you should use LinkedHashMap for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically said that you had a `Map<Object,List<Object>>`, I will limit this to that scenario.

First, create some test data.

```
Map<Object, List<Object>> halls = Map.of(new MyClass(1),
        List.of("G", "H"), new MyClass(4), List.of("C", "D"),
        new MyClass(7), List.of("A", "B"), new MyClass(3),
        List.of("E", "F"));
```

Now sort the existing map.  To preserve the sort  you can used a `LinkedHashMap` which will maintain the insertion order.  However, newly added items will not be sorted but simply added to the end.

In this case you must cast the key to your actual class name to obtain the seats as `Object` knows nothing about that method.  To reverse the sort, just reverse the order of `e1` and `e2` in the `Integer.compare` method.  Had you used `MyClass` as the key and not `Object`, this could have been somewhat easier.

```
Map<Object, List<Object>> result = halls.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(
                ((MyClass) e2.getKey()).getSeatsNumber(),
                ((MyClass) e1.getKey()).getSeatsNumber()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a,
                LinkedHashMap::new));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

The above prints.

```
seats:7=[A, B]
seats:4=[C, D]
seats:3=[E, F]
seats:1=[G, H]
```

And here is the test class with a `toString` override included.

```
class MyClass {
    int seats = 0;
    
    public MyClass(int seats) {
        this.seats = seats;
    }
    
    public int getSeatsNumber() {
        return seats;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "seats:"+seats;
    }
}
```